# StoryQ scenario where exception is expected

Tags: bdd, storyq

How do we use StoryQ to test scenario where Exception is expected?

Answer (score 4):

As far as the actual code is concerned, in the `.Then` portion of your test code, you would need to create an `Action` or `Func` to establish what was being tested, then in the `.Then` portion of the code, you would invoke that code and test the result. So for instance:

```cs
[Test]
public void AnIllegalOperationThrowsAnException()
{
    new Story("My Story)
        .InOrderTo("Do achieve something")
        .AsA("User")
        .IWant("To carry out an operation")
        .WithScenario("an exception occurs")
        .Given(InitialConditions)
        .When(TheIllegalActionIsTaken)
        .Then(AnIllegalOperationExceptionIsThrown);
}

private void InitialConditions()
{
}

private Func<string> _operation;

private void TheIllegalActionIsTaken()
{
    _operation = () => return MyTestClass.DoesSomethingWrong();
}

private void AnIllegalOperationExceptionIsThrown()
{
    try
    {
        _operation.Invoke();
        Assert.Fail("An exception should have been thrown");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.That(ex, Is.InstanceOf<IllegalOperationException>(), "The wrong exception was thrown");
        Assert.That(ex.Message, Is.EqualTo("Ooops!");
    }
}
```

The assertion handling can probably be tidied up a bit, especially your test method doesn't return a value. The FluentAssertions library, for instance, can work very nicely with an Action (but not a Func), so the code would be:

```
_action.ShouldThrow<IllegalOperationException>().WithMessage("Ooops!");
```

Answer (score 3):

BDD scenario frameworks describe the behaviour of a system from a user's perspective. What will the user see when the exception is thrown? A message? A message box?

If you can work out how the exception will be seen, it might help you to write the scenario.

Comment: I'm currently working on a platform to use StoryQ in unit testing, where it's perfectly valid that an exception is thrown.  Although StoryQ was designed for BDD, end-user-point-of-view, functional testing, it can be repurposed for other kinds of testing as well.

Comment: I'd still use the language of the customer wherever possible, even if the actual implementation involves throwing an exception. (Have you considered passing in an exception handler instead?)

Comment: there is no customer in a unit testing scenario.  See my Q&A [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226666/modifying-or-configuring-output-with-storyq)

Comment: @gregsdennis There's always a customer. See my Q&A here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3264037/363592

Comment: If I'm testing something like a repository, throwing an exception is a valid scenario and needs to be tested. There is no direct customer for the repository. There is a _consumer_, but that consumer should be able to anticipate and properly handle expected exceptions from the SUT. I agree that a customer (end-user) should never see an unhandled exception.

Comment: If you're doing BDD and outside-in properly, you talked to the support guys who are the customers of the log the exception generates, and you'll be using *their* language in the exception class. There's always a customer.

Comment: (Oh, and if you do this from an outside-in perspective and you know it might fail, you probably end up passing in an exception handler anyway, rather than just throwing it - and the real class that does the exception handling may well be called "Logger").

Comment: You still have to handle the exception as it is passed up the architecture. You don't just have some Logger make note of it and return false. My point is that throwing an exception can be valid, and there needs to be a way to test for it. My solution allows for this kind of test.

Comment: Try thinking of BDD as a description of why the class is valuable, together with an example of how to use it, rather than a test. You'll find customer language coming in more easily. Been doing this a few years now, trust me...

Comment: For an example of the kind of exception handling I'm talking about, see here: https://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/WiPFlash/Framework/Waiter.cs - that "FailureToHappenHandler" lets me do all kinds of different things, rather than being forced to catch some random exception. Much nicer.